# PHP using dirname(__FILE__) on non-dedicated server?

Tags: php, path, constants

What I trying to do is to define a constant variable in a config file:

```
DEFINE("PATH", dirname(__FILE__) . "/");
```

So that, when I want to "include" or redirect, I could do this:

```
include(PATH . "filename.php");
```

or

```
header("location: " . PATH . "logout/php");
```

But when I try doing an echo of PATH, I get this result:

```
/home/myDOMAIN/public_html
```

Am I declare the constant wrongly? (To be honest, I copy that code from Wordpress config file)

Comment: Alvaro: I cant put "2 underscores" and then a single word. The text will become bold

Comment: You can format source code with the '0101001` button. I've edited the question for you.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro for editing and providing the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Try this:

```
// sets site path for inclusion of files
define ('PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

**More Info:**

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Hi, i tried include the prefix, very strange, I got this result:
/home/myDOMAIN/public_html/home/myDOMAIN/public_html

Answer (score 1):

The `__FILE__` magic constant contains a **file system** path, not a URL. You'd need to create two different constants, e.g. `FS_ROOT` for includes and `WEB_ROOT` for URLs.

In many cases, you already have a builtin value in the $_SERVER array that can help you. Run `print_r($_SERVER)` to find out.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is your path on the server side.

Comment: So what I am doing is wrong? I try "include_once", but I got fatal_error message